# How to create a procedure for database backup for oracle 9 along with all data and structure

Tags: oracle

How do I create a procedure for database backup for oracle9, along with all data and structure.

After making the backup, I want to install new Windows XP in other computer and restore the same backup taken in Flash Ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use good old rman to create your backup of the database. Easiest is to backup on disk. If the disk backup is ready, copy the backup files to the same directory on the new machine. 
Install oracle as you are used to, on the new machine and copy the snapshot controlfiles to the new machine in the ORACLE_HOME/dbs/ location.
copy the init file or the spfile to the new machine.
Now you can restore the database to the same locations as the files were on the old machine. You can adjust to new locations by issuing a series of set newname commands for the files that you wish to put in a new location.
A very helpful resource will happen to be [Oracle9i Recovery Manager User's Guide Release 2 (9.2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96566/toc.htm)

I hope this helps.